# Definition of set of natural no.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

Okay this is definition of definition of class of natural no. and class of non limit ordinal given in Takeuti and Zaring Axiomatic Set theory. Here alpha varies over class of ordinals.

I am just asking if alpha varies over all sets. Will we still get same class.

Comment: Do you mean "$x$ in $A$ if either $x$ is empty or..."?

Comment: Several of your definitions seem to be missing words. Are you translating them from a language other than English that doesn't use "is", "a" or "the" natively?

Answer (score 0):

**This answers the question as originally posted, before the edit:**

If I understand your conditions correctly, then one of the elements of $A$ will be
$$ \{\pi,\omega_{13},\{\pi,\omega_{13}\}\}$$
Therefore, one of the *subsets of* $A$ is
$$ \{\{\pi,\omega_{13},\{\pi,\omega_{13}\}\}\}$$
And therefore one of the elements of $B$ is
$$ \{\{\pi,\omega_{13},\{\pi,\omega_{13}\}\},\{\{\pi,\omega_{13},\{\pi,\omega_{13}\}\}\}\}$$
which doesn't look like it's a natural number at all -- and certainly not anything that any conventional induction principle will apply to.

Comment: I think I was not able to ask question properly. Same question I have written. But is {π,ω13,{π,ω13}} still subset of A means K1 here. I think it is not

Comment: @Sushil: According to your original definition, "x belongs to A either x is empty set or there exist a set y such that x successor of y". If you set $y=\{\pi,\omega_{13}\}$, then we find that $x=\{\pi,\omega_{13},\{\pi,\omega_{13}\}\}$ must belong to $A$, according to this definition.

Comment: Ya right. So I think answer to question edited now is also no. Same example right. Problem is {π,ω13,{π,ω13}} is not an ordinal. Am I right?

Comment: @Sushil: Yes -- on the other hand your $A$ does include all of the non-limit ordinals and does not include any limit ordinal. So it should be "safe" (for this particular purpose) to quantify over everything in your definition of $K_{\rm I}$, as long as your definition of $\omega$ does restrict to ordinals.